# conditional in users/show page to display info or not based users having created it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-profile

This is the error I get:

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/UMUV/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #6 >>raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

This is my conditional in users/show:

```
<% if @profile_info.present? %>
  <%= @profile_info.region.name %>
<% else %>
  <%= @user.email%>
<% end %>
```

This is in the users/controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @profile_info = Profile.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: params[:id])
  end
```

I basically want to know how to not have an error when  i visit a user's profile page and the user hasn't updated their profile yet. Showing the page is working fine if i update the user's profile through "edit page" manually.

Please help with the conditional. I also have  a feeling i can create method in user.rb or users/controller, but really dont know how to implement this conditional to do what i want it to.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your show page you can replace this :

```
<% if @profile_info.present? %>
  <%= @profile_info.region.name %>
<% else %>
  <%= @user.email%>
<% end %>
```

with this:

```
<% if @profile_info.present? %>
  <%= @profile_info.region.try(:name) %>
<% else %>
  <%= @user.try(:email)%>
<% end %>
```

and also go through this post: http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html

Comment: thank you so much Abhilash. that worked!!! thank you. when i have more reputation points ill come back and upvote. thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always test an initalized object vs a saved object using new_record? -- which would make your above view look more like:

```
<% if @profile_info.new_record? %>
  <%= @user.email%>
<% else %>
  <%= @profile_info.region.name %>
<% end %>
```

also you might be able to take advantage of `try` on part of your page,  which fails gracefully if an attribute doesn't exist, like

```
@profile_info.region.try(:name)
```

Comment: thank you so much trh. both your suggestions helped! they both work pretty well. i was trying hard with present? nil? empty? etc but i guess i dont understand well the difference- so i better read more on all this bc its probable ill encounter them again soon in the future. thank you so much though- ill come back and upvote once i have the right reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Since your error is with the name `@profile_info.region.name` not being present you could change your conditional to:

```
<% if @profile_info.region.name.present? %>
    <%= @profile_info.region.name %>
  <% else %>
    <%= @user.email%>
  <% end %>
```

Or if you really want to test `@profile_info.present?` you could nest conditionals like this:

```
<% if @profile_info.present? %>
    <% if @profile_info.region.name.present? %>
      <%= @profile_info.region.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= @user.email%>
  <% end %>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thank you lflores. i had tried the present? method before but didnt help. the answers from both abhilash and trh using try worked!! thank you though for your help. this place is amazing and im glad ppl help each other here. im new to all this so im happy to see all of this. thank you.